# How do I make a very simple load screen(Not a progress bar)

Tags: kotlin

My problem is kinda simple.
I need a screen that loads before or while the R.layout.activity_full_wall_mode is loaded
I know that users hates load screens, but I have to put it there.
Progress bar doesn't work for me, because theres no way for me to track the progress.
It has to be displayed for like, 4 seconds and load the main layout

```
class FullWallModeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_wall_mode)

}
```

}

Comment: The question is what you want to achieve as there are various options. You can have another Start-Activity before that starts the final Activity, you can have an overlay with another layout or with separate Fragments. Or is your question just about opinions what people would like in terms of UI that is better than a turning wheel?

Comment: Can you show me some of overlay exemple? I don't know the keywords to search for these solutions. I tried the start-activity, but when I used Thread.sleep, it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: A layout that takes 4 seconds to load is dangerously close to triggering an ANR. Are you loading a lot of images? If so I suggest using Picasso so you can load the layout quickly and then load the images in the background.

Comment: No, it's justa a single image, medium size. Could you send me some exemples? Or maybe give me the keywords so I can find those exemples myself. I just started programming and English it's not my mother language, so I just don't know the usual termes. Thanks!